# jQuery Mobile dynamically change button color

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a list of buttons generated dynamically...

```
var output="";
var active;
var x;
var i;
var user_id=localStorage.get('user_id');#

for(x=0;x<dynamic_count;x++)
{
    output+="<div class='tbl' data-role='button' data-table_id='"+(x+1)+"'>";
    output+="<p class='center_text'>"+(x+1)+</p>";
    output+="<div>";
}

$('.table_holder').html(output).trigger('create');

//active and active_count come from AJAX request (I have missed this bit our of the code..active[0]=a table number where as active[1]= s user_id

for(i=0;i<active_count;i++)
{
    if(active[1]==user_id)
    {
        $('.tbl').find("[data-table_id='"+active[0]+"']").css('backgroundColor', 'red');
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this has no effect on the background color of the desired element. I am not sure whether it is a problem with my selector code, my css code, or a propblem with my implementation of jQuery Mobile.

I have noticed that when dynamically adding elements that need styling with jQuery Mobile I have needed to use the `trigger('create')` method to apply the css.

This obviously over writes any amended css with the original jQuery css.

Comment: You want something like this? http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/vGt2A/ active button styled differently.

Answer (score 2):

First, create a custom class e.g. `.custom-class`

**CSS:** Note that `!important` is essential to override JQM default styles.

```
.custom-class { background-color: red !important; }
```

**Code:**

Find all buttons with `[data-table_id]` attribute, compare values and apply `.custom-class`

```
var buttons = $(document).find('a[data-table_id]');

$.each(buttons, function () {
 $(this).removeClass('custom-class');
 if ($(this).attr('data-table_id') == user_id) {
  $(this).addClass('custom-class');
 }
});
```

> **[Similar demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/vGt2A/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.tbl').find("[data-table_id='"+active[0]+"']").css('background-color', 'red');
```

you are trying to assign background color like this

```
$('.tbl').find("[data-table_id='"+active[0]+"']").css('backgroundColor', 'red');
```

in jquery you need to use background-color instead of backgroundColor

Comment: unfortunately this has no effect - I believe the problem lies with the way jQuery mobile adds to the html5